# File Owner Permission on Network Share

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-sharing

I have a test fileshare which I am using to learn more about NTFS permissions. The config is as follows: Two groups, users and admins. Both groups have R/W access to share root. Selective subfolders in share root have delete permission denied for user group to prevent accidental deleting of stuff.

I've run into an issue where my user who creates a file on the share is the owner of the file but they can't delete this file. I believe it is because of their group membership (user) and the fact they put the file into the folder which disallows delete for them.

I haven't been able to figure out how I can configure the file owner to retain full control in this scenario. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Deny permissions take precedence over allow permissions.  If a deny permission is set for the "Users" group, then nobody will be able to delete the files.  (Of course, the owner, or anyone else with full access, can change the permissions on a file and *then* delete it.)

Comment: ...oops. I thought I posted this on serverfault. My users are not skilled enough to change security on files. They want to treat the network share like any other folder on their own computer and also have this safety net of not accidentally deleting important work. I'm beginning to think this is a "cant have your cake and eat it too" situtation.

Answer (score 0):

I explicitly added creator owner to the root share. The inherited permissions for Creator Owner are going all the way down to my users without the delete permissions. They cannot delete. You can view the file properties and see that the user is the owner.

So it is true, all allow rules are evaluated before any deny rules are evaluated. The presence of deny delete trumps "allow full control creator owner" thus the action is blocked by NTFS.

Harry Johnston you were correct in your comment. If you post as answer i'll accept it. Thanks for your efforts.